# REACT every time button is clicked it goes through an arbitrary list of colors but stops working randomly

Tags: reactjs

I'm writing this code that suppose every time you clicked the button it goes through the array of colors I wrote out and it works at first but it will randomly stop working and when you console.log the array that it's randomizing from you will see that it will pick a color to not keep going off of I need it to keep randomly going through the list of arrays and not to stop working randomly.

anyone wanna help?

```
function Test() {
 
  function Test2() {
    setchange(change + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
    if(change > 20) {
      setchange(change + Math.floor(Math.random() - 10))
    }
  }
  const [cchang, ssetchang] = React.useState("blue")
  const [change, setchange] = React.useState(1)
  
  return (
    <div>
        <h1>{cchang}</h1>
        <button onClick={Test2}>Randomize colors!</button>
        <div className='.flex-item'></div>
        <h1>{change}</h1>
        <div className="flex-item"></div>
        <Joe />
    </div>
  );
}

function Joe() { 
   let colorlist= ["Blue","Red","Olive","PaleGreen","Pink","Tan","Salmon","YellowGreen","DarkSalmon","DarkSeaGreen","DarkSlateBlue","DarkSlateGray","DarkSlateGrey","DarkTurquoise","Grey","Green","GreenYellow","HoneyDew","HotPink"]
   let randomizer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)
   
   function Tes(){
      ssetchangs(colorlist[randomizer]) 
     console.log(changecolor)
   }

   const [changecolor, ssetchangs] = React.useState("DarkSlateGray")
   const fine = {
    borderRadius: "10px",
    background: changecolor,
    padding: "10px",
    width: "100px",
    height: "100px",
    marginTop: "10px",
    lineHeight: "80px",
    color: "dimGrey",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: "3em",
    textAlign: "center"
  };
   
   return (
   <div>
       <h1 style={fine}></h1>
       <button onClick={Tes}>click me</button>
   </div>
   )
 }

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Do you mean in Joe or Test?

Comment: I was referring to Joe my bad should've been little more specific

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the value of `randomizer` inside the on_click handler.
When the component initially renders, it sets randomizer to a random value. When you click the button, it sets the color to randomizer. Since this is a state change, react rerenders the components and reevaluates the randomizer value. If the new randomizer value is different from the old value then everything runs just fine. However, if the value is same as previous value, then the on_click handler runs but the state is unchanged and the component is not rendered again. This means the value of randomizer never changes. To fix this select randomizer value when the button is pressed and not when the component is rendered.

```js
...
function Tes(){
    let randomizer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)
...
```

Comment: Tes function resides inside joe function. This is not about Test.

Comment: Okay. I'm an idiot, Thanks it worked

Comment: And this is exactly why proper variable naming is needed. :)